# How to launch GWT Super Dev Mode

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.5, gwt-dev-mode, gwt-super-dev-mode

After a lot of pain,Finally installed `GWT 2.5` with my `Eclipse kepler`

Now I am able to launch with Dev mode  ,i.e `Classic Dev Mode.`

By debug configuration in Eclipse aruguments tab is .

> -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl index.html -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -war E:\GWT2.5_Test\V4Workflow_V17\war com.suresh.V4Workflow

When I'm debugging Eclipse generated the URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

Which is fine.And Able to debug my code.

Actual question begins here:

I am eagerly waiting to launch my application with [Super Dev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html).

[From Docs:](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html)

> Super Dev Mode runs the GWT compiler in a web server, which is an ordinary Java application that developers can run from the command line. After the server starts up, it prints its URL:
>
> The code server is ready.
>   Next, visit: `http://localhost:9876/`

Added  the below two lines in `gwt.xml` file

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
```

I compiled the project and then I launched with `http://localhost:9876/`  nothing to happened.

Strangely no configuration guidelines founded in docs.

What I'm missing here?

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: how did you run the server? did you use the eclipse launcher? did you update the GWT eclipse plugin as well to be aligned with GWT 2.5?

Answer (score 15):

Did you configure the second launcher ?
If not :

- Open the window `"Run configurations"`
- Create a new launcher in `"Java Application"`
- In the tab `"main"` :

  - add your project (`"browse"`)
  - add in Main Class : `"com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer"`
- In tab `"argument"` :

  - add that `"-src src/ PACKAGE_NAME.PROJECTNAME"` (fictive example `"-src src/ com.google.My_project"`)
- In tab `"classpath"` :

  - select `"User Entries"`, and add the jar `"gwt-codeserver.jar"`
- Save this `Configuration`

After that, you can launch your server then launch this 2nd launcher and access to the page : `http://localhost:9876/`.

source : http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3073

Hope this will help you.